# Would you help me to understand the form between "get + [verb]" vs. "verb"?

Tags: grammar

Would you please tell me which one is correct? And why?

Could you possibly elaborate your explanations freely or readily?

> I **get bored** if I'm at home on my own all day.
>
> I **bore** if I'm at home on my own all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `"bored"` is used as an adjective, and not as a verb. In the participle `"get bored"`, **get** is the verb and **bored** is an adjective. If the sentence were `"Sitting alone at home all day _bores_ me"`, *bores* is a verb. This is why `"I bore"` is grammatically on the grey side. The verb form of *bore* would mean the act of drilling holes.

Comment: But *I bore easily* is probably possible.

Answer (score 1):

'Get' used in this way means 'to become'. So *I get bored* means I become bored. It is describing the process of changing from being 'not bored' to being bored. It implies that 'all day' is too long to be at home by oneself, and that a shorter period would be acceptable.

Your second sentence is not grammatical. It should read *I am bored*. This is a simple description of how you feel, without the sense of change. In this second version, there is no implication that the day started out OK but then became boring. It was boring all day long.